# A way to cache all db queries in memcached

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

Just a quick question to ask if it's possible to use a simple script to cache all website database queries?
Or do you have to do it the long way?

Answer (score 1):

it depends on environment you are working with... if you are using OOP DB concept, you can in your $db->query($sql) or whatever it is called method check, if key $sql exists in memcache.

If it does not, then do query and cache result with $sql as a key.

If it does exists, then return result from memcache...

Comment: Not just for object orientation. You just need a way to check memcache from within your database querying method. I suggest using an md5 hash of the query (along with its passed in values if using prepared statements) to check the cache, and save the query result in an array in the cache if not found.